# Java, Scanner, nextLine() method errors

Tags: java, input

Can you tell me what is wrong with the following code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Vector <Vector <String>> allValues = new Vector <Vector <String>>();
    Vector <String> currentTestValues = new Vector <String>();
    int tests = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++){
        int deposits = input.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < deposits; j++){
            String s = input.nextLine();
            currentTestValues.add(s);
        }
        allValues.add(currentTestValues);
        currentTestValues.clear();
    }
    for (Vector <String> v : allValues){
        for (String s : v){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

It seems to terminate after `input.nextLine();`

How to fix it?

Comment: Terminate ... *how*?

Comment: may be it means skipping.

Comment: No, I mean the program stopps. For example if I enter: 1<enter>  2<enter> asd <enter> the program stops.

Comment: Please read this link and tell if it solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: try String s = input.next();

Comment: It's not an error, the program just stops, as if it is done. @Tunaki  I tryed it, I put input.nextLine(); after the  int deposits = input.nextLine(); . But it is not filling the vector. All I have now is just an input.

Comment: I don't understand why did people downvote the question. Its a valid question. Did the people who downvote know the answer for the problem ?

Comment: @AnshulJain Yea I can't understand it either...

Comment: "terminate after input.nextLine();" is not proper problem description. Post example of your input, and expected result. Also explain how what you get is different then what expected in question itself. To do it use [edit] option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `input.nextLine()` and `currentTestValues.clear();`. This will remove your values from list and so from vector.So remove it.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Vector <Vector <String>> allValues = new Vector <Vector <String>>();
Vector <String> currentTestValues = new Vector <String>();
int tests = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++){
    int deposits = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    for (int j = 0; j < deposits; j++){
        String s = input.nextLine();
        currentTestValues.add(s);
    }
    allValues.add(currentTestValues);

}
for (Vector <String> v : allValues){
    for (String s : v){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The input will contain blank spaces, for example : "something to input", so I can't use .next();

Comment: @Poyr23 edited answer

Comment: thank you, I dind't know that  .clear() behaved this way.. I changed it to  currentTestValues = new Vector();  and now it is working.

Comment: @Poyr23 clear will clear the values from list, vector stores the reference of list .